# Very easy htaccess redirect works in the opposite way

Tags: .htaccess

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^http://agilerent.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.agilerent.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

this is not working, while this is working:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^http://agilerent.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.agilerent.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

with the negation in front of the condition. I've read a lot of material about .htaccess in last hour, but I can't realize yet what am i doing wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**`%{HTTP_HOST}` contains domain name ONLY**, e.g. `example.com`, `www.example.com` etc and does NOT include protocol. Therefore:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^agilerent\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.agilerent.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```